# Integration tests pipeline doesn't fail when testcontainer fails to start

Tags: gitlab-ci, junit5, testcontainers, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm trying to set up some integration tests using the Testcontainers Java library and JUnit 5. I want to execute these tests in a gitlab pipeline, using Maven. What happens is that if for some reason the container I'm testing against fails to start, the tests are not executed and the pipeline still succeeds. I want the pipeline to fail in that case.

Versions:

- Gitlab: 13.9
- Maven: 3.8.1
- Maven failsafe plugin: 3.0.0-M4
- JUnit jupiter: 5.7.0
- Testcontainers: 1.15.0

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is this:

```
integrationtests:
  stage: test
  retry: 2
  script:
    - mvn test failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify -DskipTests=false -Dskip.unit.tests=true -DskipITs=false
  tags:
    - run_one_at_a_time
```

In the test class I have this:

```java
    static {
        containerForTestdata =
            new FixedHostPortGenericContainer(CONTAINER_NAME)
            .withFixedExposedPort(PORT,PORT)
                        .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/api/v4/projects"))
                        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(7))
                        .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.alwaysPull());
                containerForTestdata.start();
    }
    
    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> containerForTestdata.stop()));
    }

    @BeforeAll
    protected static void retrieveToken() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        org.testcontainers.containers.Container.ExecResult tokenValue = preconfiguredGitlab.execInContainer("tail", "-1",
            "/var/opt/gitlab/.token");
        String testUrl = "http://localhost:" + PORT;
        token = tokenValue.getStdout().trim();
        connector = new Connector(testUrl, "testuser", token);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetExistingProject() throws GitLabApiException {
        Project foo = connector.getProject("foo");

        assertEquals("foo", foo.getPathWithNamespace());
    }
```

(I know the fixed host port is deprecated and against the philosophy of the testcontainers authors, but I have not found a solution for that yet. I want to get rid of it but will leave that issue for another question.)

If the container starts, the tests run as intended. But if it doesn't, 0 tests are run and the pipeline succeeds. I can run the tests locally, if the container starts normally the tests are executed, if the container fails to start it also lists 0 tests run and "build success". How do I let this fail so we will notice there is an issue with our setup? I'm not even sure in which of the moving parts I should be fixing the issue.

This is the relevant part of the output, I think.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running <my class IT>
[2021-04-06 13:22:20] INFO  - Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor)
[2021-04-06 13:22:20] INFO  - Pulling docker image: our-own-registry/testimage:latest. Please be patient; this may take some time but only needs to be done once.
[2021-04-06 13:22:20] INFO  - Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
[2021-04-06 13:22:21] INFO  - Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[2021-04-06 13:22:21] INFO  - Docker host IP address is localhost
[2021-04-06 13:22:21] INFO  - Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 20.10.5
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7964 MB
[2021-04-06 13:22:21] INFO  - Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for index.docker.io
[2021-04-06 13:22:22] INFO  - Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
[2021-04-06 13:22:22] INFO  - Checking the system...
[2021-04-06 13:22:22] INFO  - ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
[2021-04-06 13:22:22] INFO  - ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
[2021-04-06 13:22:24] INFO  - Starting to pull image
[2021-04-06 13:22:24] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  0 downloaded,  0 extracted, (0 bytes/0 bytes)
[2021-04-06 13:22:24] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  3 pending,  1 downloaded,  0 extracted, (16 KB/? MB)
[2021-04-06 13:22:24] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  2 pending,  2 downloaded,  0 extracted, (103 KB/? MB)
[2021-04-06 13:22:43] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  1 pending,  3 downloaded,  0 extracted, (54 MB/? MB)
[2021-04-06 13:28:24] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  4 downloaded,  0 extracted, (946 MB/946 MB)
[2021-04-06 13:29:10] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  4 downloaded,  1 extracted, (946 MB/946 MB)
[2021-04-06 13:29:10] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  4 downloaded,  2 extracted, (946 MB/946 MB)
[2021-04-06 13:29:10] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  4 downloaded,  3 extracted, (946 MB/946 MB)
[2021-04-06 13:29:12] INFO  - Pulling image layers:  0 pending,  4 downloaded,  4 extracted, (946 MB/946 MB)
[2021-04-06 13:29:12] INFO  - Pull complete. 4 layers, pulled in 408s (downloaded 946 MB at 2 MB/s)
[2021-04-06 13:29:12] INFO  - Creating container for image:our-own-registry/testimage:latest
[2021-04-06 13:29:14] INFO  - Starting container with ID: e3af36da30714eb78811220592299472d690ff36ad9b527c457a8f4d7aeec45b
[2021-04-06 13:29:14] INFO  - Container our-own-registry/testimage:latest is starting: e3af36da30714eb78811220592299472d690ff36ad9b527c457a8f4d7aeec45b
[2021-04-06 13:29:14] INFO  - /priceless_varahamihira: Waiting for 420 seconds for URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v4/projects
[2021-04-06 13:36:14] ERROR - Could not start container
<logging of a very good reason to not start the container>
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 835.217 s - in nl.sig.uploadunpacker.GitConnectorIT
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4:verify (default-cli) @ UploadUnpacker ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-06T13:36:15+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you please add the entire test class including a test method? Running the tests on your local machine works?

Comment: I've added some more code. The behaviour is the same locally and in the pipeline, showing 0 tests run if the container fails to start, properly executing the tests if the container starts.